# how to output the datasets from a function when names are dynamically created using assign() function?

Tags: r, function

```
library(dplyr)
```

I am trying to write a simple function that outputs several dataframes. The issue I am having that I want to assign the name of the dataframes in a function.

```
get_data <- function(diamonds,cut, clarity) {
  data_cut <- diamonds %>% filter(cut == cut)
  return(assign(paste0( "data_", "cut"),data_cut))
  
  data_cut_clarity <- data_cut %>% filter(clarity == clarity)
  return(assign(paste0("data_", "cut", "_", clarity),data_cut_clarity))
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve, I want to run the following command:

```
get_data(diamonds,cut="Ideal", clarity="SI2")
```

so that output will be two dataframes: `data_Ideal` and `data_Ideal_SI2`

When I run a function, the return() does not work. I also tired using `{{var}}` notation to assign a name, but it did not work

Comment: `assign` creates objects in the environment specified in `envir`.  You may need to check `ls()`.  Also, the `return` should be data_cut and not the `assign` i.e. `assign(paste0( "data_", "cut"),data_cut)` for the first assign, and `assign(paste0("data_", "cut", "_", clarity),data_cut_clarity)` second assign, and `return(list(data_cut, data_cut_clarity))` as a list as you can't have multiple returns.  Also, make sure to specify the `envir` in `assign`

Comment: Thank you for your explanations! I am not sure about envir, I have never created one. when i run ls() it just list all the objects i created

Comment: Also, if I run return(list(data_cut, data_cut_clarity)), the returned datafrmaes won't be having a proper name: eg data_Ideal and data_Ideal_SI2

Comment: If we use a named list i.e. either you can do `list(data_cut = data_cut,..` or `dplyr::lst(data_cut, data_cut_clarity)` as in the solution posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be better not to use `assign` and create multiple objects in the global environment.  Instead, create a single named `list` object and extract the elements with either `$` or `[[`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
get_data <- function(diamonds,cut, clarity) {
  data_cut <- diamonds %>% 
        filter(cut == cut) 
  
  data_cut_clarity <- data_cut %>% 
         filter(clarity == clarity)
  dplyr::lst(!!stringr::str_c('data_', cut) := data_cut, 
       !!stringr::str_c('data_', clarity) := data_cut_clarity)

  
}
```

-testing

```
> out_lst <- get_data(diamonds, cut="Ideal", clarity="SI2")
> names(out_lst)
[1] "data_Ideal" "data_SI2"  

> head(out_lst$data_Ideal)
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
  <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48

> head(out_lst$data_SI2)
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
  <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
```

According to `?return`

> If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.

i.e. we don't need to be explicit with `return` unless it should be from an earlier step.  In the above function, the last expression will be `return`ed

---

In addition to `:=` in naming on the `lhs`, we may also use `list` with `setNames`

```
get_data <- function(diamonds,cut, clarity) {
  data_cut <- diamonds %>% 
        filter(cut == cut) 
  
  data_cut_clarity <- data_cut %>% 
         filter(clarity == clarity)
  nm1 <- stringr::str_c('data_', c(cut, clarity))
     setNames(list(data_cut, data_cut_clarity), nm1)

  
}
```

Comment: sorry, your code does not work for me. I want the names to be generated inside the function- i have more than 200 datasets that i will need to create like that

Comment: @yuliaUU ok.  I got it.  I updated with the output I am getting

Comment: SO the issue I am having is to renme the list items to  data_Ideal and data_Ideal_SI2  since clarity and cut is specified.

Comment: also out_lst$data_cut_clarity: do not filter by cut and clarity in your example. same issue for data_cut

Comment: @yuliaUU sorry, I missed that name part to be dynamic.  Now, it should work